# Create [integration-bus] and synonymize [messagebroker] to it

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request, tag-creation-request

If we look at the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/messagebroker/info) for [messagebroker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/messagebroker):

> IBM Integration Bus (formerly WebSphere Message Broker)...

So it's clear that the software has been renamed from "WebSphere Message Broker" to "IBM Integration Bus". However, there's no tag for IBM Integration Bus — [a quick search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ibm+integration+bus) reveals that most people are using [ibm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm), [integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integration), and / or [bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bus), which are at most tangentially relevant to the actual question.

Therefore, I suggest that we create a tag called [integration-bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integration-bus) to represent the newer version and make [messagebroker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/messagebroker) its synonym, or rename (If that's possible; I don't know) [messagebroker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/messagebroker) to [integration-bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integration-bus)

*(Note: I don't know if [integration-bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integration-bus) is the right name; it seems alright to me)*

Comment: I'm not sure if messagebroker is a tag that can only be used for the IBM product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time of writing, [messagebroker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/messagebroker) contains 431 questions and its wiki excerpt reads:

> A Message Broker is a pattern which is designed for purpose of
>   consuming messages from applications and performing actions like
>   transformation , providing a point-to-point and publish-subscribe
>   pattern of message routing mechanism.

So it would appear this tag has been re-purposed. (There is no usage guidance present.)

IBM Integration Bus is now covered by the tag [ibm-integration-bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-integration-bus) which contains 179 questions. [integration-bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integration-bus) remains empty so a synonym is probably not necessary at this time.